# Repeatedly clicking the edit button causes chaos

Tags: bug, comments, edits, comment-edits

[image]

### Help!!!

I don't know quite what happened, I was getting frustrated, trying to somehow escape the backticks inside the code formatting. I clicked the <kbd>edit</kbd> button too many times, and then the above happened. Perhaps I clicked it to fast, I don't know, but I then got lots of boxes.

---

Edit:

Based on a test case below, the problem is simply caused by pressing edit while you still have an edit box open. They all go away when you press cancel anywhere once. This makes it much easier to reproduce, and, while not very important, perhaps still something to be fixed.

Note on the pattern:

When you click the first time, you get one box, as normal. When you click again, you get one extra empty box at the top, and another normal box above that. At each click, one empty box is added per existing normal boxes, plus one normal box. What is going on?

Comment: I have noticed something similar, but everything went back to normal after I finished the edit.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ I'm not saying there's anything actually bad about it, as such, but it's annoying.

Comment: I was just adding possibly helpful info. By the way, if I remember right the original comment box used to open up when the comment was edited. Now a new box pops up under the comment.

Comment: Related on SOMeta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371327/edit-a-comment-again-and-again-and-again

Comment: @StephenRauch Infact an exact cross site dupe. Still not fixed though.

Comment: Oh, and don't worry about the green G's, they're just an extension I have.

Comment: @Jǝssǝ I've reported this as bug / feature request. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313217/editing-a-comment-creates-an-edit-box-below-the-comment-not-instead-of. `CC @Artemis I'm pretty sure it was more recent than that (possibly related to the new design rollout) - I'd guess at it being days or a couple of weeks. I've been commenting a fair bit recently and only noticed today.

Comment: Apparently, it's gone. Testing...

Comment: Yup, it's back to the old 'open in comment'. `status-completed` please.