# Editing a comment creates an edit box below the comment, not instead of

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, edits

At some point a change was made (recently?) which changed the comment edit box from replacing the posted comment with an edit box, to adding the edit box below the posted comment.

Here is an example from Ask Ubuntu, but this affects all the sites I've tested.

[image: Ask Ubuntu comments]

On Area 51 it's still how it was originally, network wide.

[image: Area 51 comments]

I don't know if this is a bug (which should be fixed) or a change. If it's a change, I'm not a fan so this is a feature request to change it back.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313137/349538 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371327/4284627

Comment: For me, this is useful because I can see the entirety of my comment while also working to change something specific—there's nothing worse than having to scroll back and forth to reread something that doesn't fit into only three lines. (I just tested this with this comment, and do indeed see it happening.) If It's intended, I like it. I'm not sure how to handle my voting on this. +1 for knowing why this has happened but -1 for changing it back . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford currently this is causing the bug (linked above) so it definitely needs refining it this is intentional. I’m still not a fan of it personally, but I wouldn’t hate it terribly if they decided this was a good change